# Unable to connect to Synapse Sql using pyodbc

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, pyodbc, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to connect to Synapse Sql using managed identity using Python in Azure function. Below is the code.

```
def fun():
    server = 'servername'
    db_name = 'dbname'
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER={'+server+'};Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;DATABASE={'+db_name+'};')
    conn.timeout = 3000
    return conn
```

Im getting the below error.

```
('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to connect my Synapse sql database with  active directory authentication using python using below code:

```
import pyodbc
server = '<servername>'
db_name = '<dbname>'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER={'+server+'};Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated;DATABASE={'+db_name+'};')
conn.timeout = 3000
return conn
```

I got below error:

[image]

By help of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu18-install%2Cubuntu17-install%2Cubuntu16-install%2Cubuntu16-13-install%2Cubuntu-offline#13) I installed ODBC 13 for SQL driver and checked with that by using below code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
   
username = "username"
password = "password"
host = "<servername>"
database = "<dbname>"
authentication = "ActiveDirectoryPassword"
conn_string = sa.engine.url.URL.create(
     "mssql+pyodbc",
     username=username,
     password=password,
     host=host,
     port=1433,
     database=database,
     query={"driver": "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server","authentication": authentication},
 )
engine = sa.create_engine(conn_string, pool_timeout=30)
connection = engine.connect()
```

It connected successfully without any error.

[image]

Comment: Can you please assist me how did you install ODBC 13 driver. I am using the below. 
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql13.    Its giving me the below error.
E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql13

Comment: Any idea on how to install ODBC 13 in Azure function.It seems that the Function App (Python|Linux|Consumption) comes with pre-installed {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}.Apparently, I will be connect to synapse from Azure function.

Comment: And I tried the link you shared for odbc 13 installation, the code runs forever without any result.

Comment: Try this %sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql=13.0.1.0-1 mssql-tools=14.0.2.0-1
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev-utf16 #this step is optional but recommended*
#Create symlinks for tools
ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd-13.0.1.0 /usr/bin/sqlcmd
ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp-13.0.1.0 /usr/bin/bcp

Comment: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.